# Allow user to cancel a recurring contribution

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, user-interface

What I want is for a user to be able to log into a website, click a Cancel Membership button and that cancels the recurring contribution attached to an auto-renew membership thus making the membership expire.

Has anyone been able to do this? Using Drupal 7.54 and CiviCRM 4.7.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give your contact access to their Dashboard, then (from memory) they can access and make some limited changes to their recurring payments - ok, not from memory - some screenshots

[image: contact dashboard]

and

[image: access to 'cancel']

Comment: Do you embed this on a drupal user page?

Comment: Nope. it is just available to them, by default as a link from the bottom of their /user page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the API ContributionRecur with the action create? But not without any coding :-)

Comment: Thanks Erik. Does that solution avoid permissions issues as there currently seems to be no Drupal permission to allow a role to cancel their own contributions.

Comment: I have no idea Tony, I have not run into that issue!